# Sass auto make color variants with variables

Tags: css, sass

I have a replaceable color palette.

```
$blue, $green, $red, $purple, ...
```

I am merge thats and make a map;

```
$colors: ();
$colors:
map-merge(
    (
        "grey": $grey,
        "blue": $blue,
        "violet": $violet,
        "purple": $purple,
        "pink": $pink,
        "red": $red,
        "orange": $orange,
        "yellow": $yellow,
        "olive": $olive,
        "green": $green,
        "teal": $teal
    ),$colors
);
```

I wrote a function to call them,

```
@function color($key: "blue") {
  @return map-get($colors, $key);
}
```

And I using bootstrap color-level function (for variants): That generate color tones lighten and darken via black & white.

```
@function color-level($color-name: "blue", $level: 0) {
  $color: color($color-name);
  $color-base: if($level > 0, $black, $white);
  $level: abs($level);

  @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $color-interval);
}
```

I am set the variant levels in one map.

```
$levels: ();
$levels:
map-merge(
    (
        "100": -8,
        "200": -6,
        "300": -4,
        "400": -2,
        "500": 0,
        "600": 2,
        "700": 4,
        "800": 6,
        "900": 8
    ),$colors
);
```

I need now create new variant map with `colors()` and `levels()`. Like following map code:

```
$color-variants :

[
"grey-100": $grey-100,
"grey-200": $grey-200,
"grey-300": $grey-300,
...
"blue-100": $blue-100,
"blue-200": $blue-200,
"blue-300": $blue-300,
...
...
...
]
```

but all the methods I tried failed... how to merge it?

It works in @each, but i need static variables.

My final code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ionurboz/pen/NEEJjz)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interpolate variable names.

You can declare placeholder classes for each variant and then extend from the class, this way you can use it after the loop:

```
@each $name, $value in $colors {

    @each $tone, $level in $levels {

      %#{$name}-#{$tone}{
        background: color-level( #{$name} , $level);
        color: color-contrasted(color-level( #{$name} , $level));

        &:hover {
          background: 
            color-level( 
              #{$name} , 
              if(abs($level) >= 0, abs($level)-1, abs($level)+1)
            );
        }

        &:before {
          content: "#{$name} #{$tone}";
        } 

      }

      .#{$name}-#{$tone}{
        @extend %#{$name}-#{$tone}
      }

   }
}
```

and the use it among you project, like:

```
.a-div{
  @extend %pink-600; // use any color variant
}
```